# If condition in bash script does not work in Azure pipelines

Tags: bash, azure-pipelines

I have a simple bash script that picks up a value from a command, stores it in a variable and breaks the build using an if condition. This works on any bash terminal. Please see the code below.

```
#!/bin/bash
jq --version
PRkey=$(curl -u TOKEN:   'https://xx.yyy.zzz/abc/abc' | jq '.pullRequests | sort_by(.key)[0].status.qualityGateStatus')
echo $PRkey
if [[ "$PRkey" = "OK" ]]
then
  echo "Quality gate passed"
else
  echo "Quality gate failed"
  exit 1
fi
```

In any bash terminal I get the right output based on the string "OK" or "ERROR" , that is given in the if condition. But in Azure pipelines bash task, when I use this as an inline script, it exits always with "Quality gate failed" output. Can anyone please help.

Comment: What value for `PRkey` was received when running in the azure pipeline? what did the `echo` show?

Comment: This was the output `jq-1.5-1-a5b5cbe
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
100  3445  100  3445    0     0  10278      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 10252
"OK"
Quality gate failed`

Comment: No, that was the curl output, but the echo PRkey gives only "OK" as the output, as I have used jq to pick up that value only to be saved in the variable.

Comment: Did you get `OK` or `"OK"` ? Your if-statement looks fot `OK` without quotes.

Comment: @WalterA I got back `"OK"` with the quotes. How should I modify it to look for the quotes?

Comment: Just include them into the pattern to compare with, and write the test as `[[ $PRkey == '"OK"' ]]` or `[[ $PRkey == \"OK\" ]]`, depending on your taste.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your if-statement looks for OK without quotes.
Modify your code like @user1934428 suggested, but also put quotes around `$PRkey`:

```
if [[ "$PRkey" == '"OK"' ]]
```